# Can I use taskkill to kill a process running under a certain user?

Tags: windows

I need to kill foo.exe, but only under a certain user account.  Is this possible with taskkill?  In this case, killing all instances of foo.exe would be problematic.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
taskkill /F /T /IM foo.exe /FI "USERNAME eq target_user"
```

should do it. `/IM` specifies the image name, and the `/FI` option specifies a filter to use, in this case, a user with the username "target_user".

In any case, you'll need to be an Administrator on the local system to forcefully terminate processes in another users security context

Comment: If you do not want to hard-code username, use `%USERNAME%` or `%USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%` for current user.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't look like there's a filter to target a specific instance of a process based on its arguments (eg `taskkill /f /im notepad /fi "args contains 'd:\foo.txt'"`) 